# How to detect when a new alarm is set in Android

Tags: android, alarm

I would like to detect when a new alarm is set in Android default alarm application (I am using a Samsung device). 
I tried: filter.addAction(AlarmManager.ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED);
but it didn't work.
PS: My goal is not to detect whenever an alarm is ringing, but to use a broadcast receiver to monitor when a new alarm is created.

This is the code I am using:
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED");
        filter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.SET_ALARM");
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

From **[API Level-21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED)** and above you can use below solution in your AndroidManifest.xml for the registered BroadcastReceiver.

```
<receiver
                android:name=".YourAlarmReceiverClass"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED">
                    </action>
                </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

`ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` is sent after the value returned by getNextAlarmClock() has changed, and your `BroadcastReceiver's` `onReceive`() will be called each time when user creates a new Alarm using Alarm clock application.

Comment: Any ideas how to do it on pre Lollipop devices?

Answer (score 1):

The intent `AlarmManager.ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` will be only triggered when the next alarm to ring is changed, not when any alarm is changed. As long as you are not allowed to get a list of all active alarms in your device... probably you won't be allowed either to get an intent when one alarm is added. Ther isn't any intent which does what you ask for.